# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost'

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core

Saving user secrets throws an exception in 'Asp .Net 5 beta 7'. Specifically, when I execute this statement:

```
user-secret set Authentication:Facebook:AppId 1234567890
```

the following exception occurs:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
```

This worked correctly with `beta 6`. Does anyone know why this exception occurs and what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [breaking change](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/64).  Uninstall the old one and install the new one.

Old behavior:

```
dnu commands install SecretManager
```

New behavior:

```
dnu commands install Microsoft.Framework.SecretManager
```